# Norm of a linear map, rational numbers, continuous functions

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $\{ x_n \}$ be an injective sequence of all rational numbers in $[0,1]$. Let $\mathcal{C} ([0,1])$ with complex values be equipped with the norm:

$$||f|| = \sqrt{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{-n} |f(x_n)|^2}, \ \ f \in \mathcal{C} ([0,1])$$

Prove that for every $x \in [0,1]$, $\varphi_x : \mathcal{C} ([0,1]) \ni f  \rightarrow f(x) \in \mathbb{C}$ is a well defined linear map.

Find all $x \in [0,1]$ for which $\varphi _x$ is continuous and find its norm.

I think that the map is continuous for $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, because $|| \varphi_x (f)|| = |f(x)| = |f(x_n)|$ for a certain $n$.

By Holder inequality, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{-n} |f(x_n)|^2 \le \sqrt{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 4^{-n} } \sqrt{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  |f(x_n)|^4} = \frac{4}{3} \sqrt{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  |f(x_n)|^4}$.

But also $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{-n} |f(x_n)| \le \sqrt{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sqrt{2}^{-2n} } \sqrt{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sqrt{2}^{-2n} |f(x_n)|^2} = \sqrt{2} \sqrt{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{-n} |f(x_n)|^2}$

This works better, doesn't it?

I also don't know how to find a counterexample for $\varphi _x$ continuity when $x$ is not rational. I know that I would need to contruct a continuous function for which $f(x)|$ is not bounded by a positive number times the series by which the norm is defined.

Could you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ be fixed. For the construction of a counterexample, the following fact is useful:

For every $k \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ : $x_n \not\in (x-\varepsilon, x+\varepsilon)$ for $n \le k$.

Now, construct a function $f$ with the following properties:

- $0 \le f \le 1$,
- $f(x) = 1$,
- $f(x_n) = 0$, $n \le k$.

Use these properties to compute the norm of $f$ and conclude.

Comment: Is this going to be a sequence of functions whose graphs have a pick in $x$ and $f(x)=1$ and there are slopes on both sides of $f(x)=1$ which are getting steeper and steeper as $k \rightarrow \infty$ ?

Comment: Could you also help me justify that the map is continuous for rational $x$? Maybe I should apply the Holder inequality in the reverse direction?

Comment: Concerning the continuity for rational $x$: In that case, you have $x_n = x$. And you have to estimate $|f(x_n)|$ by a constant times $\|f\|$. But this is trivial, isn't it?

Comment: Would $\sqrt{2}$ be that constant? Could we use $2 |f(x_N)| = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{-n} |f(x_N)| \le \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{-n} |f(x_n)|$?

Comment: I think the constant depends on $n$: $|f(x_n)| \le C \, \sqrt{2^{-n} \, |f(x_n)|^2} \le C \, \|f\|$. So $C = 2^{-n/2}$ or something like that.